# What's the name of the mod in Direwolf20 1.10.2 that has these buttons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, mod-identification

What is the name of the mod in Direwolf20 1.10.2 that has these buttons?
I want to use it in my Sky Factory pack.

[image: buttons]

Answer (score 4):

This is [Quark](http://quark.vazkii.us).  More specifically, the [Chest Buttons](http://quark.vazkii.us/#management-chest-buttons) feature.